# Youtube API in PHP > Upload only transfer 76 chunks on Big File Size

Tags: php, youtube, upload, filesize, chunks

I try to upload videos with PHP to my Youtube Channel. These videos are HD and big file size (around 4GB). So when I try to upload a video around 200mb there is no problem and the script upload all chunks (more then 100)
But when I try to upload my real videos (4GB) it always stops after chunk 76 and only uploaded 79691776 bytes

> Error: "A service error occurred: Failed to parse Content-Range header."

Because the script is working on smaller files I think I set up all correctly

- Created a webbase OAuth2 Credential
- I am Using Xampp for local server
- test with untouched original script:
- https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/resumable_upload.php
- Took correct apiclient "composer require google/apiclient:~2.0"
- set php ini execution time to 24hours so it not seems to be a timeout

Here is the script:

```
<?php

/**
 * Library Requirements
 *
 * 1. Install composer (https://getcomposer.org)
 * 2. On the command line, change to this directory (api-samples/php)
 * 3. Require the google/apiclient library
 *    $ composer require google/apiclient:~2.0
 */
if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php')) {
  throw new \Exception('please run "composer require google/apiclient:~2.0" in "' . __DIR__ .'"');
}

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();

/*
 * You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from the
 * {{ Google Cloud Console }} <{{ https://cloud.google.com/console }}>
 * For more information about using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs, please see:
 * <https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication>
 * Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
 */
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = '**********************************.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = '******************';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
    FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

// Check if an auth token exists for the required scopes
$tokenSessionKey = 'token-' . $client->prepareScopes();
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }

  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

if (isset($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey]);
}

// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $htmlBody = '';
  try{
    // REPLACE this value with the path to the file you are uploading.
    $videoPath = "test.mp4";

    // Create a snippet with title, description, tags and category ID
    // Create an asset resource and set its snippet metadata and type.
    // This example sets the video's title, description, keyword tags, and
    // video category.
    $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
    $snippet->setTitle("Test title");
    $snippet->setDescription("Test description");
    $snippet->setTags(array("tag1", "tag2"));

    // Numeric video category. See
    // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
    $snippet->setCategoryId("22");

    // Set the video's status to "public". Valid statuses are "public",
    // "private" and "unlisted".
    $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
    $status->privacyStatus = "public";

    // Associate the snippet and status objects with a new video resource.
    $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
    $video->setSnippet($snippet);
    $video->setStatus($status);

    // Specify the size of each chunk of data, in bytes. Set a higher value for
    // reliable connection as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
    // value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
    $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    // Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called
    // with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately.
    $client->setDefer(true);

    // Create a request for the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
    $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);

    // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
    $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
        $client,
        $insertRequest,
        'video/*',
        null,
        true,
        $chunkSizeBytes
    );
    $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));


    // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
    $sizecount = 0;
    $ii = 0;
    $status = false;
    $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
    while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
      $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
      $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);

      $sizecount = $sizecount+$chunkSizeBytes;
      $ii = $ii+1;
      echo $ii." - ".date('H:i:s')." - ".$sizecount."</br>";
    }

    fclose($handle);

    // If you want to make other calls after the file upload, set setDefer back to false
    $client->setDefer(false);


    $htmlBody .= "<h3>Video Uploaded</h3><ul>";
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
        $status['snippet']['title'],
        $status['id']);

    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';

  } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }

  $_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey] = $client->getAccessToken();
} elseif ($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID == 'REPLACE_ME') {
  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Client Credentials Required</h3>
  <p>
    You need to set <code>\$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID</code> and
    <code>\$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID</code> before proceeding.
  <p>
END;
} else {
  // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
  $state = mt_rand();
  $client->setState($state);
  $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
  <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Video Uploaded</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?=$htmlBody?>
</body>
</html>
```

I only hide my api key and secret in here and I put a check into the loop

```
  $sizecount = $sizecount+$chunkSizeBytes;
  $ii = $ii+1;
  echo $ii." - ".date('H:i:s')." - ".$sizecount."</br>";
```

After i started Uploading a 4GB Video and wait for around 70-80 seconds folloing appears:

```
1 - 07:02:15 - 1048576
2 - 07:02:16 - 2097152
3 - 07:02:17 - 3145728
4 - 07:02:18 - 4194304
5 - 07:02:19 - 5242880
6 - 07:02:20 - 6291456
7 - 07:02:21 - 7340032
8 - 07:02:22 - 8388608
9 - 07:02:23 - 9437184
10 - 07:02:24 - 10485760
11 - 07:02:24 - 11534336
12 - 07:02:25 - 12582912
13 - 07:02:26 - 13631488
14 - 07:02:27 - 14680064
15 - 07:02:28 - 15728640
16 - 07:02:29 - 16777216
17 - 07:02:30 - 17825792
18 - 07:02:31 - 18874368
19 - 07:02:32 - 19922944
20 - 07:02:33 - 20971520
21 - 07:02:34 - 22020096
22 - 07:02:34 - 23068672
23 - 07:02:35 - 24117248
24 - 07:02:36 - 25165824
25 - 07:02:37 - 26214400
26 - 07:02:38 - 27262976
27 - 07:02:39 - 28311552
28 - 07:02:40 - 29360128
29 - 07:02:41 - 30408704
30 - 07:02:42 - 31457280
31 - 07:02:43 - 32505856
32 - 07:02:44 - 33554432
33 - 07:02:45 - 34603008
34 - 07:02:46 - 35651584
35 - 07:02:46 - 36700160
36 - 07:02:47 - 37748736
37 - 07:02:48 - 38797312
38 - 07:02:49 - 39845888
39 - 07:02:50 - 40894464
40 - 07:02:51 - 41943040
41 - 07:02:52 - 42991616
42 - 07:02:53 - 44040192
43 - 07:02:54 - 45088768
44 - 07:02:55 - 46137344
45 - 07:02:56 - 47185920
46 - 07:02:57 - 48234496
47 - 07:02:57 - 49283072
48 - 07:02:58 - 50331648
49 - 07:02:59 - 51380224
50 - 07:03:00 - 52428800
51 - 07:03:01 - 53477376
52 - 07:03:02 - 54525952
53 - 07:03:03 - 55574528
54 - 07:03:04 - 56623104
55 - 07:03:05 - 57671680
56 - 07:03:06 - 58720256
57 - 07:03:07 - 59768832
58 - 07:03:07 - 60817408
59 - 07:03:08 - 61865984
60 - 07:03:09 - 62914560
61 - 07:03:10 - 63963136
62 - 07:03:11 - 65011712
63 - 07:03:12 - 66060288
64 - 07:03:13 - 67108864
65 - 07:03:14 - 68157440
66 - 07:03:15 - 69206016
67 - 07:03:16 - 70254592
68 - 07:03:17 - 71303168
69 - 07:03:18 - 72351744
70 - 07:03:19 - 73400320
71 - 07:03:20 - 74448896
72 - 07:03:20 - 75497472
73 - 07:03:21 - 76546048
74 - 07:03:22 - 77594624
75 - 07:03:23 - 78643200
76 - 07:03:24 - 79691776
A service error occurred: Failed to parse Content-Range header.
```

a few thoughts what could be:

- maybe fopen isn't able to read the whole file (too big)
- maybe I have to configure something more in php.ini
- maybe RAM is full but I set RAM to -1 (infinity) in php.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it! Here is the solution:

I am using Windows and XAMPP is only available in 32bit

so: `filesize();` could not handle my video files

32Bit is limited to 4GB files, so I just installed Apache 64bit and PHP 64 bit and now it works.

Here the guide: https://danielarancibia.wordpress.com/2015/09/27/installing-apache-2-4-and-php-7-for-development-on-windows/

Comment: Thanks for undeleting this. However, answers must be 100% answer material. You can refer to a related problem briefly if you wish, but that belongs in a new question. Would you edit this accordingly? Don't forget you can also self-accept to indicate this one is answered (click the tick mark to the left of the question). If you can make those edits and ask a new question, let me know and I'll +1 for the purposes of general encouragement!

Comment: done :) Thank you!

here is a link to my new problem post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47860441/9090675